# Prevent user to change checkbox value conditionally in Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

** How to prevent user to edit check-box value if user doesn't have permission. I want to display model if user doesn't have permission to edit. So, disabling input box wont work**

```
Vue.component('edit-deal', 
     data: function(){
        showDeal: true,
        hasPermission: false
},
template:`
    <label>Show deals </label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="showDeal">
`
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an event listener on `click` of the checkbox, and if there's no permission, `emit` an event to the parent component to show a modal:

```js
const editdeal = Vue.component('edit-deal', {
  template: '#edit-deal',
  data: () => ({ showDeal: true, hasPermission: false }),
  methods: {
    checkPermission(event) {
      if(!this.hasPermission) {
        this.$emit("show_modal");
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { editdeal },
  data: () => ({ showModal: false }),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div><editdeal @show_modal="showModal=true"/></div>
  <div v-if="showModal">No Permission Modal</div>
</div>

<template id="edit-deal">
  <div>
    <label>Show deals </label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="showDeal" @click="checkPermission">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but i want to show modal(alert boxes) with some link so disabling input box won't open modals

Comment: @AvikPradhan I updated the answer with a simple demo, you can set your modal component in the parent and set it to close using ``showModal=false``